# Ordering the execution of BeforeScenario attribute hooks

Tags: .net, attributes, hook, specflow, scenarios

I have a feature file with some tags:

MyFeature.feature:

```
...
@RestoreDB
@SomeAction
Scenario outline: ...
...
```

and binding cs file:

MySteps.cs:

```
[Binding]
public class MySteps:
{
   [BeforeScenario("RestoreDB")]
   public void RestoreDB() { ... }

   [BeforeScenario("SomeAction")]
   public void SomeAction() { ... }
}
```

SpecFlow executes BeforeScenario in an unordered sequence.

Is it possible to set ordering of execution RestoreDB tag always before SomeAction tag??

Comment: What is "SomeAction" doing? Stating its purpose will help to answer your questions.

Comment: for example: SomeAction - to restore system state for the test execution after another test.
Actually, I think it's no matter. I just want to know is it possible to specify for the SpecFlow that this tag always will be execute before another tag if they are marked into BeforeScenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to specify the order in which BeforeScenario hooks are executed. You can see a discussion of this issue on the SpecFlow github site [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/199).

I can understand why you may use BeforeScenario to execute a "RestoreDB" method (e.g. to set up the system for the test), however I'd be wary about restoring "system state" which you mention in your comment; what exactly is this "system state"? If this "system state" is not related to your DB data, then I'd question why you'd put this in the BeforeScenario.

A SpecFlow scenario should execute a feature in it's entirety. Instead of setting up system state in the BeforeScenario you should include the steps as part of the scenario instead. If that step is used in many places you could use a SpecFlow [Background](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background) to achieve this, as opposed to using a BeforeScenario hook.

Comment: It exactly what I wanted to know. What's about the "system state". Let's assume, before test execution, I should restart the services of the application which I test. First time I added SomeAction tag to the 500 tests and after that I understand that I need to restore DB before SomeAction in the some tests.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Couldn't you use AfterScenario("SomeAction") to clear up these tags at the end of every scenario? This way you would be guaranteed that they'd run in the correct order.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to fix it a little bit. But I expected from SpecFlow that if I will add the tags FirstTag and below SecondTag it will be execute in an ordered sequence or another explicit way to do it for beforescenario hooks

Comment: I do agree with you @DmytroUkraine. I too (and a lot of others judging by the post mentioned in my answer!) expected a way of ordering these but at the moment it's not possible.

Comment: Don't forget about `[BeforeFeature]` too.